# How to empty sqlite3 database in django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

Running through the polls tutorial I ran this line:

```
q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

Now, I've already ran:

```
python manage.py flush
```

But when I save and check the ID, I noticed that the id is still incrementing.

```
>>> q.save()
>>>q.id
3
```

Why is the id value not 1? Why are the id values preserved even though the db was destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by deleting all tables using `manage.py sqlclear` before using `manage.py flush` which empties the data in all tables.

Then you can re-sync the tables according to your defined model with `manage.py syncdb`.

Maybe it would make your life easier to use south to make database migrations or some Django Extensions.